# Losing Style trigger after Code-Behind changes background/foreground

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to make buttons like discord's, which have three states. Active (after clicked), unactive completely and mouse over. All these three states change colors as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLYgB.png

The problem comes after the Click event, because to change it to its basic state I set the BG/FR directly. When I do that, the mouse over event stops working in that button after that. Any ideas how can I set the bg/fr to its initial value without affecting the trigger from the style?

I tried using dynamic color but it wouldn't even set at all. So I'm kinda lost, tbh.

Style from the buttons:

```
        <Style x:Key="MainMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF303136"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF6F7074"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="30, 0, 0, 0">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2A2A32"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBBBCB8"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Click event:

```
        private void Main_Menu_Swap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button s = e.Source as Button;

            if (s != null)
            {
                InicioButton.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF303136");
                InicioButton.Foreground = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF6F7074");
                RelatoriosButton.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF303136");
                RelatoriosButton.Foreground = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF6F7074");
                AdministracaoButton.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF303136");
                AdministracaoButton.Foreground = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF6F7074");

                s.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF42464F");
                s.Foreground = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFCFD6DC");
            }
        }
```

Buttons:

```
        <Button x:Name="InicioButton" Content="Início" Click="Main_Menu_Swap" Style="{StaticResource MainMenuStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="32" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="15" Padding="30,0,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="RelatoriosButton" Click="Main_Menu_Swap" Content="Relatórios" Style="{StaticResource MainMenuStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="32" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="15" Padding="30,0,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="AdministracaoButton" Click="Main_Menu_Swap" Content="Administração" Style="{StaticResource MainMenuStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="32" BorderThickness="0" Focusable="False" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="15" Padding="30,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: This is due to [dependency property value precendence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence). Don't set those properties from code-behind. Use setters and triggers for everything.

Comment: So the best choice would be setting the initial values by Button.Click? I thought about doing that but I can't think of a way to reset all buttons to the initial value except the clicked one, since all of them uses the same style.

Comment: Your best choice would be to use setters and triggers for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dependency properties overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview#data-binding):

> Bindings are treated as a local value, which means that if you set another local value, you will eliminate the binding. For details, see Dependency Property Value Precedence.

If you are interested in the `Click` event, then you should use a `EventTrigger` (or `VisualStateManager`) to manipulate the `Button` state using XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="#FF303136" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="#FF6F7074" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Padding="30, 0, 0, 0">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                Duration="0:0:0" 
                                To="Coral" />
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                Duration="0:0:0"
                                To="White" />
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

But in case you just want to provide button click feedback you should trigger on the `Button.IsPressed` property:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="#FF303136" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="#FF6F7074" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Padding="30, 0, 0, 0">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                       
          <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Coral" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="White" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

### Edit

The reason why the background color is set back is because of the `IsMouseOver` trigger. Your described solution where you switch styles from a `Button.Click` event handler is not clean to answer your question.

You want the `Button`to change color when it is clicked (selected) and at the same time apply mouse over effects.
I therefore recommend to replace `Button` with a `ToggleButton`. `ToggleButton` offers two states out of the box (selected and unselected):

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenuStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="#FF303136" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="#FF6F7074" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Padding="30, 0, 0, 0">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Coral" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="White" />    
          </Trigger>

          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#FF2A2A32" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="#FFBBBCB8" />    
          </Trigger>

          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
              <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Coral" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="#FFBBBCB8" />
          </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>    
</Style>
```

Comment: This does indeed change the background (specifically the second option), but it's temporary and it returns to the default option right after the click event.

I actually just managed to fix my problem with a code-behind that simply sets back the style of every button to its initial one and the source button to a new style, with a different bg/fr. This actually worked pretty well - Do you think this is a good solution?

Comment: basically "AdministracaoButton.Style = unactive_style" and "s.Style = active_style"

Comment: To switch styles in an event handler is not very clean in my opinion. I added a better solution to the answer.